# find and rename multiple files on multiple folder

Tags: file, find

Finding a way to rename multiple files on a multiple folder

folder i.e. I have file called "jobsforms.html.bak" on a multiple folder under:

```
/home/sites/juk/jobsforms.html.bak
/home/sites/juan/jobsforms.html.bak
/home/sites/pedro/jobsforms.html.bak
/home/sites/luois/jobsforms.html.bak
```

I want to rename all the files found as: "jobsforms.html" how can I do that.
I was trying to do this aproach.

```
find /home/sites -name "jobsform.html.bak" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}"/jobsform.html' -- {} \;
```

Anyone can help me how to go about to do this.
Than you,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe the output of `find` to `awk`, using the `sub` function  to remove a substring from the filename:

```
find /home/sites -name "jobsforms.html.bak" | awk '{ori=$0; sub(/\.bak$/,"",$0); system("mv \""ori"\" "$0)}'
```